# Which statistical test should I use in my diary study of repeated measures when trying to establish within-person effects?

Tags: regression, mixed-model

I am having real trouble analysing the data for my Psychology dissertation. I am investigating the effects of physical activity on psychological well-being both at the between-person level (i.e. generally if people are more active, they have higher psychological wellbeing) but also at the within-person level (i.e. do people report higher psychological wellbeing on days they are more active?). I asked participants to wear a pedometer and report their step number each day, and a self-report measure of their physical activity along with 2 measures of psychological wellbeing. The data is either stacked or nested (I'm not sure) as each participant has 4 different measures on each of the 7 days of their participation.

I am calculating each person's overall level of physical activity as the mean of their within-person measures. Daily level of physical activity is regarded as the deviation from this mean. So I am looking to say that on days where participants are more active they report higher wellbeing (within-person effect).

Due to the nature of my data collection, I cannot identify the appropriate test to use. IVs are Pedometer step count and a self-report measure or physical activity. DVs are a general Mental wellbeing scale and a Satisfaction with Life scale.